# How to combine JS files in Magento 2.2.4

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.4, merge-css

I am using Magento 2.2.4 and want to combine external JavaScript files but, In the admin section I didn't find the options for it under the Developer section.

Comment: External js merge is not available in magento system. You need to download those to your magento local and call accordingly then only you can merge the js files or css files.